# solve arithmetic equation in the list python

Tags: python

```
arr =[11*11,12*12,13*13]
```

it should multiply the values and store like

```
arr = [121,144,169]
```

In python how do I multiply the elements in the list
Thanks in advance,

Comment: @ialarmedalien is right, you should show what you have tried, and ,not be rude, you can just probably find the answer with a simple Google search

Comment: @Bhavani, did you even try to run the code? That's exactly what Python does!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you didn't even bother to try it first. That's exactly the default Python's behaviour:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, May 16 2018, 17:50:09) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180502 (Red Hat 8.1.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> arr = [11*11,12*12,13*13]
>>> arr
[121, 144, 169]
>>>
```